# Many To Many Relation - delete item

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Models:

```
class Cecha(db.Model):
    __tablename__='cechy'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    nazwa = db.Column(db.String)

cechy_asort = db.Table('cechy_asort',
    db.Column('id_cechy', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cechy.id')),
    db.Column('id_asortymentu', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('asortymenty.id')))

class Asortyment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'asortymenty'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nazwa = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True, index = True, nullable = False)

    zamowienia = db.relationship('Zamowienie', backref='asortyment', lazy='dynamic', cascade='all,delete')
    cecha = db.relationship('Cecha', secondary=cechy_asort, backref=db.backref('asortymenty', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='joined')

    def ma_ceche(self, id_cechy):
        cecha = Cecha.query.filter_by(id=id_cechy).first()
        if cecha is None:
            return False
        if not cecha in self.cecha:
            return False
        return cecha

    def dodaj_ceche(self,id_cechy):
        if not self.ma_ceche(id_cechy):
            cecha = Cecha.query.filter_by(id=id_cechy).first()
            self.cecha.append(cecha)
            db.session.commit()

    def usun_ceche(self,id_cechy):
        if self.ma_ceche(id_cechy):
            cecha = Cecha.query.filter_by(id=id_cechy).first()
            self.cecha.remove(cecha)
            db.session.commit()

class Grupa_asort(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'grupy_asort'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nazwa = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True, index = True)

    asortymenty = db.relationship('Asortyment', backref = 'grupa_asort', lazy='dynamic', cascade='all,delete')
```

The problem is with deleting item from table Asortyment if there is relation:

```
 Asortyment.query.filter_by(id_grupy=id_grupy).delete()
```

The error is:
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation: update or delete on table "asortymenty" violates foreign key constraint "cechy_asort_id_asortymentu_fkey" on table "cechy_asort"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1446) is still referenced from table "cechy_asort".

Comment: You have created tables with foreign key constraints and trying to delete in isolation. Eg, you are trying to delete a record with `id-1446`. which is referenced in table `cechy_asort`. You need to first delete record in  `cechy_asort` and delete here. A simple way is in SQL when you create the table. You may like to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` in your `CREATE TABLE` SQL.

Comment: Generally, records are not deleted. An attribute to mark/flag a record as Deleted is used and such tuples are ignored for further action when he flat is set.

Comment: You may look at this link too if it suits https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477806/remove-a-relation-many-to-many-association-object-on-sqlalchemy?rq=1

Comment: I already told you so. You need to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` at `CREATE  TABLE` SQL statements. What is the dbms you are using?

Comment: Please post your code here for other struggling users to get benefitted from what you achieved. And Never forget to **Vote** for the solution that worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cechy_asort = db.Table('cechy_asort',
    db.Column('id_cechy', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cechy.id')),
    db.Column('id_asortymentu', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('asortymenty.id', ondelete="CASCADE")))
```